# Stimulate users to ask how they can achieve something (or: how to avoid the XY problem on SU)

Tags: feature-request

I noticed people sometimes asking questions about a specific solution to their problem instead of asking how to achieve their goal (also known as [the XY problem, as explained on Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). For example [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/802453/ram-part-numbers-meaning) the user wants to replace a faulty RAM. He needs to know what the specs are of his new RAM. He *thinks* he can deduce that from the partnumber of his existing RAM. So his question is: "What does this part number mean?", while I think it would be better if he asked something like: "When replacing RAM, what specs should I look for?". Another [example of this type of question](https://superuser.com/questions/802646/two-windows-in-two-partition-isolated-from-each-other).

I think this is important, because asking how to achieve a goal instead of asking how to achieve a specific solution challanges people to give qualitative better answers and thus gives better solutions. Additionally, it builds a better knowledge base for this site, because achieving a specific goal is probably what other users are also interested in.

My proposal is to add some instruction to the ["Asking"-section](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) of the help, and ask users to rephrase their question if it is asks for a specific solution.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Oliver-Salzburg: I didn't know that it was called like that. Thanks. +1 for your comments and added it to the question.

Comment: While I agree that the XY problem is a problem most new users will fall back to, the problem is just that: most people don't read the manual at start (in this case the help pages). XY problem type questions aren't necessarily bad, it's just that they usually derive from a lack of context (which is mentioned in the help), which makes so that any other user is constrained to the OP's solution.

Comment: I sort of feel that "What specs should I look for?" sort of promotes product recomendations.  The question "What does this part number mean?" allows somebody to explain a generic part number for memory.